# NginX Proxy Pass Infinite Loop

Tags: nginx

Can anyone explain why removing the last slash produce infinite loop? At chrome browser it results `http://localhost//`

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/tracker; // infinite loop
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/tracker/; // not infinite loop
}
```

But if I add suffix in location directive, it is fine.

```
location /tracker {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/tracker; // not infinite loop
}

location /tracker {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/tracker/; // not infinite loop
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case of:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/tracker;
}
```

would produce a 302 redirect loop if `/tracker` was an upstream directory (for example). Upstream might issue a 302 redirect to append a `/`, which `proxy_pass` would strip off again.

You are aliasing URIs - so either both the location and the destination should end with `/`, or neither should end with `/`.

Comment: what do you mean of upstream directory?

Comment: By upstream I mean `localhost:8080`. You don't state what application is listening on `localhost:8080`, but (possibly) something is making it redirect from `/tracker` to `/tracker/`.

Comment: It's just simple Spring Framework apps that returns plain HTML

Answer (score 1):

Check in your "tracker app" if have a trailing slash, mostly framework have this feature for SEO like.

Anyway you can track it with access log.

Comment: yeah trailing slash did it, so must I standardize all mapped URL to with or without trailing slash?

Comment: Depend by content of link, you can check the standard from google webmaster tools (https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html)